# How can one show that $f(x) = 3 + 5^{\sin(x)}$ is continuous on $[0, 2\pi]$ but also differentiable on $(0, 2\pi)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can one show that $f(x) = 3 + 5^{\sin(x)}$ is continuous on $[0, 2\pi]$ but also differentiable on $(0, 2\pi)$? This has to do with verifying the usage of the Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we can use composite function properties so

$f(x)=3+x , g(x)=5^x, h(x)=sinx$

All of these functions are continuous and differentiable on R therefore

f°g°h(x)=3+5^sinx is also continuous and differentiable on R